# How to remove a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

I think I must be using CSS 2.1, because the style overflow-x is not available.
So in the code below I have the headings for a grid, and the pageLength Id puts in a vertical scrollbar for the contents of the grid. Unfortunately it also puts in a horizontal scrollbar, which I do not need. "overflow-x" does not work, so what does?
The CSS looks like;

```
#pageLength
{
    height: 400px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And the table for the grid looks like this;

```
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Morning Only
        </th>
        <th>
            Afternoon Only
        </th>
        <th>
            Approved
        </th>
        <th>
            Cancel?
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody  id="pageLength">
    <%: Html.EditorForModel()%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***EDIT - responding to request for Page Source

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Morning Only
        </th>
        <th>
            Afternoon Only
        </th>
        <th>

            Approved
        </th>
        <th>
            Cancel?
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody  id="pageLength">

    <tr>
        <td>
            Wed, December 8, 2010
        </td>            
        <td align="center">

            No
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            No
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            No
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input name="[0].CancelFlag" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].CancelFlag" type="hidden" value="false" />

            <input name="[0].AnnualLeaveBookedId" type="hidden" value="36" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Wed, December 15, 2010
        </td>            
        <td align="center">
            No
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            No
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            No
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <input name="[1].CancelFlag" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].CancelFlag" type="hidden" value="false" />
            <input name="[1].AnnualLeaveBookedId" type="hidden" value="37" />
        </td>

    </tr>
```

.
.
.

Comment: I am using FF. But it needs to work in IE6+

Comment: Actually in ie6 I find that the height I am setting in the style for TBODY get applied to each TR.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is the output? Perhaps the source code viewed from within the browser. We cannot guess what the output is of your <%: Html.EditorForModel()%>, and I think that the problem lies in that part.

Comment: IIRC, overflow-x should work in IE6, IE was the first to implement these.

Comment: There is an additional problem I am finding in ie6, which is that the hight style in the class is applied to each TR, so there is a huge gap between in each. The simple way out is to apply the CSS class to a div outside of the table. The problem is that the Header fields are the first to disappear in a downward scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think #pageLength should have a fixed width & height.
Also, #pageLength children nodes should not exceed #pageLength's width, be aware of [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) (take into account margins, paddings & borders), maybe you should use a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)).